# Arredondamento para Cima - C#

Tags: c#

Uso um programa pra corrigir meu estoque do arquivo fiscal sped que eu envio pra receita. Mas estou com problemas pois produtos unitários estão saindo com valor quebrado.

Exemplo abaixo, o produto tinha (50) unidades depois q eu passo o programa ele fica com valor quebrado (13,089) eu queria arrendondar para cima (note que estou dividindo por 3,82)

```
|H010|7506195153574|UN|50|5,93|296,5|0|||001|296,5| (original)

|H010|7506195153574|UN|13,089|5,93|77,62|0|||001|296,5| (alterado)
```

---

meu código:

```
string[] strArray = File.ReadAllLines(@"original.txt");
StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"alterado.txt");
foreach (string str in strArray)
{
    string[] strArray2 = str.Split(new char[] { '|' });
    if (strArray2[1] == "H010")
    {
        strArray2[4] = Math.Round((decimal)((Convert.ToDecimal(strArray2[4]) / 382M) * 100M),3).ToString();
        string str2 = string.Join("|", strArray2);
        writer.WriteLine(str2);
    }
}
```

---

Só avisando estou estudando C# faz pouco tempo e vou começar meu curso apenas ano que vem, estou me virando com tutorial na net, mas não estou entendendo nada na parte logica. :( :(

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema. O que você mostra no alterado, está todo errado, é isto?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1cz5da1c(v=vs.110).aspx) ao invés de [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
strArray2[4] = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(strArray2[4]) / 382M * 100M).ToString();
```

`Ceiling` arredonda sempre pra cima. `Round` arredonda pra acima apenas se a parte decimal for maior que `0.5`.